# PhotoSwipe auto-rotation

Tags: autorotate, photoswipe

everyone!
I have a problem for using PhotoSwipe plugin.
I am using PhotoSwipe in mobile webview(Android and iphone).
when I click photoswipe image item,then some images are rotated 90 degree.
I found this problem is occured in the captured images with camera.
[Origin image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmiGn.png)
PhotoSwipe version is latest and I tested all browsers PC and mobile.
How can I fix this problem?
please help me, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

you should set the property `correctOrientation: true`

```
//plugin option parameters
var options = {
    quality : 80,
    destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    allowEdit : false,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    targetWidth: 1024,
    targetHeight: 768,
    popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
    correctOrientation: true,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false
};
```